# ODBC: SQLSetConnectAttr actual attribute constant name

Tags: windows, odbc, ado

At the moment I encountered **SQLSetConnectAttrW** call with attribute constant equal to either 0 or 1(**SQLSetConnectAttrW(0x1231231, 0, 0, -6)**). And so I cannot distinguish what is actual SQL_ATTR_* define name so that I can refer to it further. I tried to look through ODBC header files, but ended up with no success in finding what this could be. So my question is what are these constants names?

PS: ADO internally makes this sort of call and I have to figure out what is this being made for.

Best regards, Alexander Chernyaev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two attributes are **SQL_ATTR_MAX_ROWS** and **SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT** and it's ok to pass them to connection handle as @bohica stated before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing SQLSetConnectAttr(0xNNNNNNNN, 0, 0, -6) then the first argument is a connection handle (a pointer), the second is the attribute to set (I'm not aware of an attribute of value 0), the 3rd is irrelevant and the 4th is SQL_IS_INTEGER implying it is a numeric attribute. Are you sure it is attempting to set attribute 0? Where did you get that information from?

Comment: I've got this information from hooking ODBC API up and trying to intercept these calls running simple ADO cscript.exe-based console VBScript. It's totally understood that the script itself could not pass this attribute's ID because ADO's API didn't allow that. And I'm pretty sure it is trying to set attribute 0 as well as attribute 1. The test set up is a simple MySQL community server up and running along with its' 32-bit ODBC driver installed so that I am able to run ADO VBScript applications.

Comment: I turned ODBC trace on in odbcad32 program and here is what it shows:
cscript.exe  te fdc-1288 EXIT  SQLSetConnectAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
  SQLHDBC             0x03089210
  SQLINTEGER                   1 <SQL_ATTR_MAX_ROWS>
  SQLPOINTER                 0
  SQLINTEGER                  -6 

cscript.exe  te fdc-1288 ENTER SQLSetConnectAttrW 
  SQLHDBC             0x03089210
  SQLINTEGER                   0 <SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT>
  SQLPOINTER                 0
  SQLINTEGER                  -6

Comment: I saw these SQL_ATTR_MAX_ROWS and SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT values before but I doubted it's valid to pass them to connection since they refer solely to statement handles only... Somebody, please confirm whether it is correct to use these attributes along with connection handle...

Comment: I'm afraid, it is possible to pass statement attributes to a connection - especially if they are ODBC 2 or before attributes. Read the spec.

Comment: would you kindly specify where documentation states that?

Comment: The ODBC specification states that. The updated docs say it is deprecated but I know loads of apps which still do it. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and search for "The ability to set statement attributes at the connection level by calling SQLSetConnectAttr has been deprecated"